# printing data from a struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a nested array of structures in the following form:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* e_name;
    char* e_lastname;
}emp_name;

typedef struct
{
   emp_name name;
   int id;
}emp;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  int cod=100;
  emp job[3];
  for (i=0;i<3;i++)
  {

     scanf("%s",&job[i].emp.e_lastname);
     job[i].id=cod;
      cod++;
 }
     for (i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
       printf("%s",job[i].emp.e_lastname);
         printf("%d\n",job[i].id);
  }
 system("PAUSE");   
    return 0;
  }
```

but the program hangs in the printing part, why is that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problem:

**First** you want to access:

```
job[i].name.e_lastname
```

not

```
job[i].emp.e_lastname
```

**Second** You should have:

```
scanf("%s",&job[i].name.e_lastname);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%s",job[i].name.e_lastname);
```

You do not pass `&` since it is an array you are passing to the scanf function.

**Third** problem you should allocate memory to your `char *e_lastname` and `char *e_name` camps of the `struct emp_name`.

Note that:

**scanf**

int scanf ( const char * format, ... );

> Reads data from stdin and stores them according to the parameter
>   format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments.
>
> The **additional arguments should point to already allocated objects**
>   of the type specified by their corresponding format specifier within
>   the format string. ([source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/))

So you want this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  int string_size = 10;
  int cod=100;
  emp job[3];


  for (i=0;i<3;i++) // Allocate space for the string you will access.
  {
  job[i].name.e_name = malloc(sizeof(char)*string_size);
  job[i].name.e_lastname = malloc(sizeof(char)*string_size);
  }

  for (i=0;i<3;i++)
  {

     scanf("%s",job[i].name.e_lastname);
     job[i].id=cod;
     cod++;
 }
     for (i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
       printf("%s",job[i].name.e_lastname);
         printf("%d\n",job[i].id);
  }
 system("PAUSE");   
    return 0;
  }
```

Consider the fact that using scanf is unsafe, because:

> If you use the %s and %[ conversions improperly, then the number of
>   characters read is limited only by where the next whitespace character
>   appears. This almost cetainly means that invalid input could make your
>   program crash, because input too long would overflow whatever buffer
>   you have provided for it. No matter how long your buffer is, a user
>   could always supply input that is longer. A well-written program
>   reports invalid input with a comprehensible error message, not with a
>   crash. ([source](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/String-overflows-with-scanf.html))

Nevertheless, their are some workaround that you can do to use scanf (check them [here](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/String-overflows-with-scanf.html))

Instead of scanf you can use [fgets](http://itee.uq.edu.au/~comp2303/Leslie_C_ref/C/FUNCTIONS/fgets.html). fgets allows you to limit the data that will be placed in your buffer.

Comment: Up-voting your solution. Yours is a perfect working solution. While mallocing you don't have to do sizeof(char) as char is 1 byte. You can straight away do `malloc(string_size);`. Can reduce a function call this way :)

Answer (score 1):

You really need to be careful with pointers and what is allocated or not.
I have rewritten your code but with the wrong solution. check comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct emp_name {
    /* 
     * now there you had just char*. this decares
     * a pointer to some memory but no memory is allocated.
     * if you were going with that approach you should initialize
     * the struct and assign those values to something you malloc'ed().
     * This version suffers from fixed size and a possible buffer overflow if
     * you chose scanf to write the data in the buffer.
     */
    char e_name[512];
    char e_lastname[512];
    /*
     * try to follow conventions. your previous struct declarations
     * were anonymous. if it caught an error you wouldn't know in which
     * struct it would be.  good practices here: link1 (bottom) 
     */
} emp_name_t;

typedef struct emp {
    emp_name_t emp;
    int id;
} emp_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int cod=100;
    emp job[3];
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
        /*
         * check out this excelent post for a secure alternative:
         * link2 (bottom)
         */
        scanf("%s",&job[i].emp.e_lastname);
        job[i].id=cod;
        cod++;
     }
     for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
         printf("%s",job[i].emp.e_lastname);
         printf("%d\n",job[i].id);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

link1: [openbsd style(9)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=style&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html)

link2: [disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf)

Answer (score 0):

I see you have:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* e_name;
    char* e_lastname;
}emp_name;

typedef struct
{
   emp_name name;
   int id;
}emp;

emp job[3];
```

So what is **.emp** doing in the following line? Its not a member of any structure

```
job[i].emp.e_lastname
```